# Date format getting automatically changed in java

Tags: java, date, date-format

I have a date in the given format : "2016-12-09T01:05:00.148Z"
When I try to get this date using "application/json" format , it converts to "1481245500148".

Please suggest, how can it be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1481245500148 is the number of milliseconds.

This can be convert this back to ISO 8601  by doing:

```
long ms = 1481245500148L;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(ms);
System.out.println(instant);
```

Which outputs:

```
2016-12-09T01:05:00.148Z
```

Comment: I need this in form of date and not Instant